# Difference between Sync Phases and Waves?

Tags: argocd

Argo CD can synchronize (i.e. apply manifests) in order. The ordering is determined by [*phase*](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/sync-waves/), *wave*, resource kind (e.g. `Namespace`, `Deployment`), and name.

There are 3 phases:

- `PreSync`
- `Sync`
- `PostSync`

Within the `Sync` phase can be one or more *waves*, assigned to resources using the `argocd.argoproj.io/sync-wave` annotation, and has integer values, with the lower-numbered waves being applied first.

The question is - what's the purpose of sync phases when the ordering can already be achieved using sync waves? Or - what's the difference assigning a resource to the `PreSync` phase vs. assigning to a low-numbered sync wave?

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** phases are used to order the running of *scripts*; waves are used to order the `apply` of application resources.

---

The `PreSync` and `PostSync` sync phases are used to run [resource hooks](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/resource_hooks/) - scripts that are supposed to run to completion. For example:

- `PreSync` - can be used to run data migration *scripts*
- `PostSync` - can be used to run a smoke test *script*, or a *script* to send a Slack message

Because hooks are scripts, they tend to be `Pod`, `Job` or Argo Workflows.

**Hooks are meant to be deleted** after it runs; if and when exactly depends on the [hook deletion policy](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/resource_hooks/#hook-deletion-policies).

On the other hand, resources applied within a sync wave are not scripts, but objects/services/config that are **meant to remain as part of the application after the sync** is over. Sync waves exists so you can dictate the order these resources are applied (e.g. make sure one service is healthy before starting another one).